# Get and Set Properties in c sharp Not working

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Ok here is my code it doesn't work even i copied one code from book and applied many restriction throw get and set properties but nothing is working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get 
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                      throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

                name = value;

            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.name = null;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}**
```

Null string still go through and no exception at all. Am i doing something wrong.

Comment: `p.Name` not `p.name`

Comment: Why do `Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.name);`? Wouldn't it be easier and equivalent to do `Console.WriteLine(p.name);`?

Comment: Actually i was writing some message and other stuff in console.writeline  but when i copied it i deleted everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the private field `name` directly, It will not trigger the `Set` against Property `Name`.

You should be accessing the Property not the backing field. So `p.name` should be `p.Name`.

EDIT: It would be better if you have your property and related logic in a separate class like:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then create the instance of that class in your `Program` class like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass p = new SomeClass();
        p.Name = null;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", P.name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now you will not notice that you can't access `name` field, instead only the `public` property `Name`

Comment: Out of interest, why does this compile? I know the field is being accessed from the same class, but it's from a static context and it's referring to a field that isn't within the `this` context. I would have thought it would generate a compiler error but it doesn't....

Comment: @Habib change the second P.Name to p.name.  I would but its only 1 letter

Comment: @Sean, Main is the static method, but it is creating an instance of Program class in itself. It is not directly accessing the instance member.

Comment: @Habib they should both be lowercase not uppercase =P

Comment: @Habib Thanks for clearing it up. One question if object can change the field data than whats the point of having get and set method shouldn't it restrict all access to this field.

Comment: @user2838938, the better way would be if you have your property and related stuff in another class, and then create instance of that class in `Program`, this way you will not be able to access the private field, you can only access it through property. Since you are doing all the stuff in a single class, you can directly access private instance. I will update my answer with related code.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `name`(field) not `Name`(property). 
You can access private fields from the same file. That is why (may be mistakenly) you are able to access `name`. To trigger the Exception you have to do,

```
Program p = new Program();
p.Name = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid further confusion you can use the underscore convention for local variables (especially when they share the same name as public variables).

For instance:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
```

I know this doesn't answer the question (many already have) but it WILL help you in the long run...and since the issue is with scope I figured it was relevant :P

Answer (score 1):

```
p.name = null;
```

Should be `p.Name`